# How to convert from DbGeometry to String using Automapper?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, automapper, azure-mobile-services

I have a spatial table with Geometry columns. My entity is as follows:

```
public class Tile 
{
    public DbGeometry Geometry { get; set; }
}
```

and I'm using a data transfer object to return the Tile class to my clients. I also create Tiles from my client so I'd like to convert from a string (Well Known Text representation of a Geometry) to a DbGeometry field. Here's my DTO:

```
public class TileDto
{
    public String Geometry { get; set; }
}
```

Now my first thought was to create custom converters like so:

```
public class DbGeometryToStringConverter : ITypeConverter<DbGeometry, string>
{
    public string Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var geom = (DbGeometry) context.SourceValue;
        return geom.AsText();
    }
}
public class StringToDbGeometryConverter : ITypeConverter<string, DbGeometry>
{
    public DbGeometry Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var wkt = (string) context.SourceValue;

        var geom = DbGeometry.FromText(wkt);
        if (geom == null || !geom.IsValid) return null;

        return geom;
    }
}
```

I then set the AutoMapper config to map between the two using:

```
 AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
 {
     // Configure our custom type converter for the DbGeometry class
     cfg.CreateMap<DbGeometry, string>().ConvertUsing<DbGeometryToStringConverter>();
     cfg.CreateMap<string, DbGeometry>().ConvertUsing<StringToDbGeometryConverter>();

     cfg.CreateMap<Tile, TileDto>();
     cfg.CreateMap<TileDto, Tile>();
 });
```

But this gives me the error: **Type 'System.String' does not have a default constructor**

I tried to use the ResolveUsing method but it also gave me a NullReferenceException. I've made sure that all the columns have a geometry column so I'm not sure how it's null.

```
cfg.CreateMap<Tile, TileDto>()
    .ForMember(tileDto => tileDto.Geometry,
               map => map.ResolveUsing(tile => tile.Geometry.WellKnownValue));
```

This is used inside an ASP.NET application for an Azure Mobile Service backend so my controller where the debugger breaks with the error is:

```
public class TileController : TableController<TileDto>
{
    private DatabaseContext _context;

    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        _context = new DatabaseContext();
        DomainManager = new TileDtoToTileMappedEntityDomainManager(_context, Request, Services);
    }

    public SingleResult<TileDto> GetTile(string id)
    {
        // MY ERROR HAPPENS HERE
        return Lookup(id);
    }
}

public class TileDtoToTileMappedEntityDomainManager : MappedEntityDomainManager<TileDto, Tile>
{
    public override SingleResult<TileDto> Lookup(string id)
    {
        return LookupEntity(t => t.Id == id);
    }

    public override Task<TileDto> UpdateAsync(string id, Delta<TileDto> patch)
    {
        return UpdateEntityAsync(patch, id);
    }

    public override Task<bool> DeleteAsync(string id)
    {
        return DeleteItemAsync(id);
    }
}
```

I'm using AutoMapper 3.2.1 since Azure Mobile Service SDK is dependent on it. I'm trying to create DTOs for my entities in my Azure Mobile Service so I'm not entirely sure if it's my AutoMapper configuration that's wrong or if it's how my entities are set up. I followed the steps from [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/06/18/insert-update-related-data-with-1-n-relationship-using-net-backend-azure-mobile-services.aspx) to create the DTOs. Is there a configuration change I need to make in AutoMapper to get this to work?

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine :) add code line where you get error

Comment: @Backs I've updated my question with my controller code where the debugger stops with the thrown error. What kind of application did you test this with? I'm wondering if it's the MappedEntityDomainManager code that's causing this...

Comment: yes, I think problem is in MappedEntityDomainManager, because without it, just plain convertion from Tile to TileDto and back is working fine

Comment: look at this article, maybe you will find something http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/05/19/mapping-between-database-types-and-client-type-in-the-net-backend-using-automapper.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Backs the issue was with my AutoMapper configuration. Using the MapFrom method instead of ResolveUsing did the trick.

Here's my configuration:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Tile, TileDto>()
       .ForMember(tileDto => tileDto.Geometry,
                  map => map.MapFrom(tile => tile.Geometry.AsText()));

    cfg.CreateMap<TileDto, Tile>()
       .ForMember(tile => tile.Geometry,
                  map => map.MapFrom(tileDto => DbGeometry.FromText(tileDto.Geometry)));

    cfg.CreateMap<Tile, TileDto>();
    cfg.CreateMap<TileDto, Tile>();
});
```